# Override addon function

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, monkeypatching

I'd like to override a method inside the DockYard `ember-changeset-validations` addon so I can translate the error messages via I18n.
This is the file where the function is located: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset-validations/blob/master/addon/utils/get-messages.js

Is there any way I can override this `getMessages()` method without having to fork the whole repo?

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset-validations#overriding-validation-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ember-cli use define/require pair. So you can somewhere in initializer put code

```
let oldImplementation = require('ember-changeset-validations/utils/get-messages').default;
define('ember-changeset-validations/utils/get-messages', ['exports', 'ember', 'ember-changeset-validations/utils/messages'], function (exports, Ember, defaultMessages) {
  // override module implementation here
  exports['default'] = oldImplementation;
});
```

In such way you'll redefine module ( so you should keep module's interface the same ). But  it's ugly hack